# Need to override WebDriver's methods

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

What we have:

```
driver = WebDriver.Chrome..

def get_driver():
#wrapper for webdriver
    return driver
```

further - lots of:

```
get_driver().find_el...
get_driver().implicitly_wait..
```

and so on in many files

I need to override couple of webdriver's functions (such as `find_elements_by_xpath` and `find_elements_by_id`) without changing code in many files.

What was my approach:
Create a class `get_driver()` instead of function, inheritance it from my driver and override functions I need. Something like that:

```
class get_driver(driver):

    def find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath):
        return WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

It even looked like going to work, but any time I try to call my get_driver().find_element_by_xpath(...) my class creates another instance of driver and open a new browser. How could I avoid this?

Comment: what do you want to achieve by overriding these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be different ways to do it. But below approach works fine for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()


class PatchDriver():
    driver = None

    orignal_method = None


    def __find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath):
        return WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))

    @staticmethod
    def patch(driver):
        PatchDriver(driver)
        return driver

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

        self.orignal_method = driver.find_element_by_xpath
        driver.find_element_by_xpath = self.__find_element_by_xpath


driver = PatchDriver.patch(driver)

driver.get("http://tarunlalwani.com")

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a)[3]")

elem.click()

driver.quit()
```